# VBA : For loop exiting without returning the value

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following piece for code to simulate stock prices using stochastic process

```
Function varswap1(s0, r0, sigma0, t) As Double
  Rnd (-10)
  Randomize (999)

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, r As Double
Dim stock() As Double, dt As Double
Dim per As Integer
  per = WorksheetFunction.Round(t * 252, 0)

  ReDim stock(per)
  stock(1) = s0
  dt = 1 / 252

  For i = 1 To per  
    stock(i + 1) = stock(i) * Exp((r0 - 0.5 * sigma0 ^ 2) * dt + sigma0 * Sqr(dt) * WorksheetFunction.NormSInv(Rnd()))
  Next

  varswap1 = WorksheetFunction.Average(stock)
End Function
```

In this code, I ran debugging by placing a break point at Next and the entire For loop is working absolutely fine. The problem is after completing the loop the function exits and `#VALUE!` error is displayed in the cell.

I am not able to figure out what is wrong with this code. 
Will be thankful if anyone can help me with it.

Comment: The second to last loop iteration should be giving a subscript error when it tries to evaluate `stock(i + 1)`, because `stock` only has `per` elements (and is zero based).

Comment: Think @Comintern has nailed it - also `Average()` will only accept a maximum of 255 values to calculate.

Comment: Ok yes. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you edit the question and show some typical values for the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Const n As Integer = 252

Function varswap1(s0, r0, sigma0, t) As Double
  Rnd (-10)
  Randomize (999)

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, r As Double
Dim stock() As Double, dt As Double
Dim per As Integer
  per = WorksheetFunction.Round(t * n, 0)

  ReDim stock(per)
  stock(0) = s0  ' First item in the array has index 0
  dt = 1# / n    ' Avoid integer division, 1/252 = 0

  For i = 1 To per
    'Each stock depends on the previous stock value:
    stock(i) = stock(i - 1) * Exp((r0 - 0.5 * sigma0 ^ 2) * dt + sigma0 * Sqr(dt) * WorksheetFunction.NormSInv(Rnd()))
  Next

  varswap1 = WorksheetFunction.Average(stock)
End Function
```

I saw two issues and one suggestion.

One is the array `stock` goes from `0..252` but you assign values to `1..253` so it crashes.

Also there is a possible integer division resulting in `dt=0.0`. I updated the definition to make the intent clear that the division is to be done after the conversion from integer to double. Lastly, I moved the magic number 252 to a constant.